# How to get key value value based on deserializeUntyped response

Tags: api, salesforce, apex-code

Here is my JSON body

What I need key value

For example: if  tenantcode = 200 What I need is "2"

```
string str = '{"10":{"name":"IP Auth","tenantcode":"204"},"11":{"name":"Registration","tenantcode":"205"},"13":{"name":"API Demo","tenantcode":"206"},"2":{"name":" Test","tenantcode":"200"},"29":{"name":"testing 2","tenantcode":"207"},"3":{"name":"Training ","tenantcode":"201"},"30":{"name":" Test222","tenantcode":"208"},"31":{"name":"Martin","tenantcode":"212"},"32":{"name":"API Demo Customer","tenantcode":"209"},"4":{"name":"Adrian ","tenantcode":"202"},"9":{"name":"Stephen","tenantcode":"203"}}';

  Map<String, Object> resultsMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(str);

    for(object obj : resultsMap.values()){
         Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>)obj;
          system.debug('utlevel30description---'+(String)data.get('tenantcode'));
      }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You'll simply have to iterate until you find the right record since you're looking for a key by its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating over the values of the map and you don't have access to the keys anymore.

You can try the following in order to have access to both the key and the value.

```
string str = '{"10":{"name":"IP Auth","tenantcode":"204"},"11":{"name":"Registration","tenantcode":"205"},"13":{"name":"API Demo","tenantcode":"206"},"2":{"name":" Test","tenantcode":"200"},"29":{"name":"testing 2","tenantcode":"207"},"3":{"name":"Training ","tenantcode":"201"},"30":{"name":" Test222","tenantcode":"208"},"31":{"name":"Martin","tenantcode":"212"},"32":{"name":"API Demo Customer","tenantcode":"209"},"4":{"name":"Adrian ","tenantcode":"202"},"9":{"name":"Stephen","tenantcode":"203"}}';

Map<String, Object> resultsMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(str);
for(String key : resultsMap.keySet()){
    Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>)resultsMap.get(key);
    system.debug('utlevel30description---'+(String)data.get('tenantcode'));
    if((String)data.get('tenantcode') == '200'){
        system.debug('your key is ' + key);
    }
}
```